# TabView without contents in QML

Tags: qt, tabs, qml, qt5, qtquick2

I'd like to provide a user with a tab bar to select one of the elements for filtering.

```
ColumnLayout
{
    anchors.fill: parent
    TabView
    {
        Layout.fillWidth: true
        Tab { title: "all" }
        Tab { title: "even" }
        Tab { title: "odd" }
        Tab { title: "multiple of 3" }
        Tab { title: "prime" }
    }
    TableView
    {
        Layout.fillHeight: true
        Layout.fillWidth: true
        model: mymodel

        TableViewColumn
        {
            role: "name"
            title: "name"
        }
        TableViewColumn
        {
            role: "number"
            title: "number"
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, about 100px of blank space is shown between the TabBar and TableView.

I don't want to create 4 TableViews - I'd rather alter the model. I know there's `TabBar` in `QtQuick.Controls.Private` but I'd rather avoid using private components since they can be changed at any time.

Is there any way to show only the TabBar without accessing the private components, for example by hiding that blank space?

I'd rather not override style, since on Android it will give me awful, non-native look

Answer (score 0):

There's no reliable way of achieving this that I know of.

There's a platform/DPI-dependent hack, though. You can user a slider to figure out the ideal height:

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.2

Window {
    id: window
    visible: true
    width: 400
    height: 400

    ColumnLayout {
        anchors.fill: parent
        spacing: 0

        TabView {
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.preferredHeight: s.value

            Tab {
                title: "all"
            }
            Tab {
                title: "even"
            }
            Tab {
                title: "odd"
            }
            Tab {
                title: "multiple of 3"
            }
            Tab {
                title: "prime"
            }
        }
        TableView {
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            model: ListModel {
                ListElement {
                    name: "A"
                    title: "1"
                }
                ListElement {
                    name: "B"
                    title: "2"
                }
                ListElement {
                    name: "C"
                    title: "3"
                }
            }

            TableViewColumn {
                role: "name"
                title: "name"
            }
            TableViewColumn {
                role: "number"
                title: "number"
            }
        }
    }

    Slider {
        id: s
        minimumValue: 0
        maximumValue: 50
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom

        Text {
            text: s.value.toFixed(0)
            anchors.left: parent.right
        }
    }
}
```

[image: tabview gif]

For me, on Desktop, it's 29 pixels.

Comment: But it isn't portable. On Android I have to support multiple screens with various DPI

Comment: Nope, it's not. It's hacky.

Comment: Hmmm... And would it be possible to make the the content very small, e.g. 1px high?

Comment: The content of the `TabView`? The `contentItem` property is readonly, so no.

Comment: Yes, but the content of each of the tabs are the children objects

Comment: You can try that yourself by adding 1x1 `Item`s as children of the `Tab`s. It doesn't work.

Comment: I know that it doesn't work by default, the items are resized.

Comment: So there's your answer. :p